# Insert in unordered map when expanding a macro in global scope

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a macro that creates functions which are then called from an executable via the function name in command line arguments. A minimal example is:

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAKE_FUNCTION(func_name, custom_message) \
void func_name(){std::cout << #custom_message << std::endl;}

MAKE_FUNCTION(func_foo, "foo called")
MAKE_FUNCTION(func_bar, "bar called")

std::function<void()> get_function_from_string(std::string func_string){
    if(func_string == "func_foo")
        return func_foo;
    else if(func_string == "func_bar")
        return func_bar;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    get_function_from_string(argv[1])();
}
```

This is now run with

```
$./a.out func_foo
"foo called"
```

I want to do this without the help of the `get_function_from_string` function. For this I tried creating a static unordered map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()> > global_map;

#define MAKE_FUNCTION(func_name, custom_message) \
void func_name(){std::cout << #custom_message << std::endl;} \
global_map[#func_name] = func_name;

MAKE_FUNCTION(func_foo, "foo called")
MAKE_FUNCTION(func_bar, "bar called")

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    global_map[argv[1]]();
}
```

But this does not compile saying:

```
$./a.out func_foo
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
MAKE_FUNCTION(func_bar, "bar called")
```

Is there a convenient way to do this?

Comment: Do you *have* to use a macro for this?

Comment: @cigien Yes. I need to do it using macros (the minimal example does not make it seem like its needed)

Comment: How about the `func_name` function that gets generated; can that be a lambda? Then you could use the macro at function scope.

Comment: That'd work if you don't have to reference the function outside the map. But this smells like legacy code that had been written prior to the introduction of lambdas into C++.

Comment: @Alex OP *has* tagged this with c++11 though.

Comment: Just updated the tag to c++17!

Comment: Notice that you invoke UB when input string is wrong in first snippet (and would throw in second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hideous as it looks you could try do this, but I'm pretty sure it is afflicted by static-initialization ordering, which wouldn't be good:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()> > global_map;

class AddNameToMap
{
public:
    template<class Fn>
    AddNameToMap(std::string name, Fn&& fn)
    {
        global_map.emplace(name, std::forward<Fn>(fn));
    }
};

#define MAKE_FUNCTION(func_name, custom_message) \
void func_name(){std::cout << custom_message << std::endl;} \
namespace { AddNameToMap antm##func_name##__LINE__(#func_name, func_name); }

MAKE_FUNCTION(func_foo, "foo called")
MAKE_FUNCTION(func_bar, "bar called")

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    global_map["func_foo"]();
    global_map["func_bar"]();
}
```

Comment: `constinit` will help, but that's only in c++20.

Comment: Not really any better way to do it unfortunately. You could make it "neater" by marking the initialization function with the constructor attribute under GCC, or insert it into a linker section and call it similar to the CRT, but either way it'll be an abomination.

Comment: Thanks! Would writing a getter function resolve static-initialisation ordering? Something like 
`auto& get_global_map() {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()> > global_map{};
    return global_map;
}`